# Timeout Exception while sorting bigger List

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I'm trying to solve [big-sorting](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/big-sorting/problem) problem from [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com). I have below solution for that:

```
static String[] bigSorting(String[] unsorted) {

    List<BigInteger> newValues = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();

    String[] newValuesArray = new String[unsorted.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.length; i++) {
        newValues.add(new BigInteger((unsorted[i])));
    }

    Collections.sort(newValues);

    for (int i = 0; i < newValues.size(); i++) {
        newValuesArray[i] = newValues.get(i).toString();
    }
    return newValuesArray;
}
```

Although my solution is working if input is short but for lengthy input it giving the `TimeoutException`

As I come to know the testcase which causing issue is :

> ```
> total input = 7693
> And Values :
> 123121
> 22
> 2
> 23123
> 12312
> 2
> 8400195277734975809347292766456055069919837818826921595732345474832683881284408515491064519242069257576624629524016550879441266062080977804902962370685876553901611732
> And So on...until 7693 values
> ```

So I have question here regarding `Collections.sort(newValues);` weather it causing the issue as there is huge numbers to be sort so it might be taking time or something else ?

Please find below snap regarding output :

[image]

And this is what it takes as input

[image]

Comment: Please include both the problem and your code in the question body.

Comment: _below solution_... Where?

Comment: "but for lengthy input ... ???" you stopped in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: You can just delete the question, write the complete question, and then undelete it later...

Comment: Sorry, I was facing issue with code upload now updated. thanks for downvotes

Comment: Still not self-contained. You never said what is "this problem" in the question body.

Comment: @user202729, i have linked *this*

Comment: [Questions should be self-contained.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18669/should-posts-be-self-contained)

Comment: The whole point of the HackerRank challenge is to come up with a solution that is fast enough. You came up with a solution that is not fast enough. So using BigInteger is not the right solution. Finding the right solution is the purpose and the fun of hackerrank. You probably need to do something with a custom Comparator that compares in a smart way without having to go through a BigInteger first.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, Thanks of quick reply.

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(unsorted.length)` or better use `BigInteger[]` and `Arrays.sort/parallelSort`. Best probably is using ones own Comparator.

Comment: @NarendraR Regarding your solution - you don't have to convert strings to numbers to compare them. Usually a number with more digits is bigger than a number with fewer digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break your code into sections:

```
List<BigInteger> newValues = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();

String[] newValuesArray = new String[unsorted.length];
for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.length; i++) {
    newValues.add(new BigInteger((unsorted[i])));
}
```

The performance of this section depends on two things:

1. The size of `unsorted`.
2. The lengths of the strings in `sorted`.

The reason that string lengths matter is that converting a decimal string to the internal representation used by `BigInteger` is expensive.  For a single string with D digits, the time complexity is O(D<sup>2</sup>).  So the overall complexity is O(ND<sup>2</sup>).

```
Collections.sort(newValues);
```

This sorting step is typically O(NlogN), or O(NlogND) in the worst case<sup>1</sup>.

```
for (int i = 0; i < newValues.size(); i++) {
    newValuesArray[i] = newValues.get(i).toString();
}
```

This is O(ND<sup>2</sup>) because of the `toString()` call.

So looking at this overall we have a typical complexity of O(ND<sup>2</sup> + NlogN).

(*The complexity analysis about is pretty rough and ready.  If I've made any major mistakes, please comment ...*)

---

One thing we can see from the above analysis is that the cost of the conversions from strings to `BigInteger` and back *could be dominating* the sorting cost.  Especially if the most numbers have many digits.

Can we avoid this?  Yes!  It is possible to write a `Comparator<String>` that can compare decimal numbers without converting them to binary.

The second thing we could optimize is the sorting.

- In some cases, the `Collections::sort` method actually copies the collection to an array, sorts the array, then copies the sorted array back to the list.
- There another method called `Arrays::sort`.  If you use this, you may be able to avoid one or more list <-> array copying steps.
- There is yet another method called `Arrays::parallelSort`.  If there are C cores available, using this method could give (up to) C-fold speedup.

---

<sup>1 - The typical case is occurs when the numbers in the list are significantly different, and you can typically compare a pair of them in O(1).  The worst case is when the nnumbers are all the same (or close) and comparison typically is O(D).</sup>

Comment: Thanks Stephen. This is what I was expecting. Why this code was taking much time. Now it's clear

Comment: Somr notes: (1) Every objects in Java arr references. Copying an array (not deep copy) take time ~ its length in all cases, which is negligible. (2) Arrays::sort does not have guaranteed O(n log n) performance.

Comment: 1)  Time taken is O(N).  It is not significant compared with the O(ND^2) term, but it may still be significant compared with not copying.  Especially for large N (and small D).  And this is not an array to array copy.  It is array to list and list to array.  2) That's not what the Javadoc says (Java 8).  `Arrays::sort(Object[])` uses a version of "timsort".  It is O(NlogN) for randomly ordered inputs, and better if the input is partially or fully ordered.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `BigInteger`, sort the `String`s directly.

Using the natural ordering of `String`s won't work, since 2 will come after 10.

However, you can define your own `Comparator<String>` that supports numeric `String`s. That `Comparator`'s `compare` method will first compare the `String`s lengths. It will return -1 if the first String is shorter and 1 if it's longer.

If the two `String`s have the same length, you would iterate on the characters of the two `String`s and compare one character at a time. If all the characters are equal, you return 0. Else you return -1 or 1 depending on whether the first character for which the `String`s are different is smaller or larger in the first `String`.

Here's a possible implementation of the `Comparator`'s `compare` method:

```
public int compare(String one, String two) {
    if (one.length != two.length)
        return one.length() - two.length();       
    for (int i = 0; i < one.length; i++) {
        char c1 = one.charAt(i);
        char c2 = two.charAt(i);
        if (c1 != c2) {
            return c1 - c2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then:

```
static String[] bigSorting(String[] unsorted) {
    Comparator<String> comparator = ... // the above mentioned Comparator
    Arrays.sort(unsorted, comparator);
    return unsorted;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I though and added in a comment 14 seconds earlier :)

Comment: Eh.. don't you think it's not very nice for Hackerrank if we're going to give full solutions here? I tried to *not* give a full solution in my comment, only a hint. What's the point of a run Hackerrank challenge this way?

Comment: Thanks @Eran, although code was not required. I'm clear now regarding my doubt.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt We have some rules regarding questions from external sites and the rule is "don'tneed to treat them specially". A spoiler warning may be useful.